# Specific C++ Macro

Tags: c++, templates, macros

I would like a C++ Macro that will turn something that looks like this:

```
safe_cast<Type>(object)
```

into

```
Assert(dynamic_cast<Type>(object))
```

Is this possible?

I could do it using: `safe_cast(Type, object)`, but it's not what I am after.

Comment: A request for a macro whose expansion text is not valid C cannot be the subject of a valid C question.  Tags edited.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a template function instead?

Comment: It cannot be done with macros (at least not if you want it to work for types like `map<int, string>`) but you can easily do it with a function.

Comment: Why a macro!? Why!?

Comment: Because job security: They are harder to debug.

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be a macro, but surely a function template will be fine:

```
template <class U, class T>
U safe_cast(T *const obj) {
    auto * const p = dynamic_cast<U>(obj);
    assert(p);
    return p;
}
```

Call as you would `dynamic_cast` with a pointer.

Comment: why use `const` here?

Comment: Thank you, will this be inlined?

Comment: @ZhuZhi I'd be very surprised if it weren't.

Comment: @Default just a habit. It doesn't need to change later :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a macro. There's no reason why we cannot use a template function here, and so we should!

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T safe_cast_helper( U& u, std::true_type )
{
    try {
        return dynamic_cast<T>(u);
    }
    catch (std::bad_cast& e)
    {
        assert( false && "Exception thrown!" ); // Or something better!
    }
}

template <typename T, typename U>
T safe_cast_helper( U& u, std::false_type )
{
    auto ptr = dynamic_cast<T>(u);
    assert( ptr );
    return ptr;
}

template <typename T, typename U>
T safe_cast( U& u )
{
    return safe_cast_helper<T>( u, std::is_reference<T>::type() );
}
```

You can use this as you would normally use a `dynamic_cast`, with either a reference or a pointer. I would, however, recommend improving the error reporting somewhat! Perhaps a write to log or something would be prudent before assert'ing out.